# I updated Ubuntu and the fan stopped

Tags: fancontrol

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 for a month and the fan was always running at high speed (I am using an Acer Aspire E-14).  I updated my system today and the fan is quiet.  Is this normal?  I expected performance enhancements but I don't know if this is ok.  Cheers.

Comment: If the fan does not run, that would be problematic. If it simply runs quietly, that's fine. Have you tried putting the computer under some stress, ie gaming for a bit, to try to get the fans to an audible level, to ensure they are working?

Comment: Yes, I ran a Matrix computation with multiple threads and it is still quiet.  The machine is not hot but the fan seems to be stopped (no noise, no vibrations)

Comment: This seems related. It's even the same brand. I'll keep looking https://askubuntu.com/questions/4214/fan-wont-turn-on-how-do-i-turn-it-on-manually

Comment: You might also try this, to ensure that they work https://askubuntu.com/a/249192/647604

Comment: From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1696532 for the acer 5515

Acer in its infinite un-wisdom decided to hand over fan control to windows vista "e-power" software. Upon system boot the fan would start up on post then shut down and wait for the os to load and then wait for e-power to start up. On this particular model only Vista has the software to run the fan. So if you install win xp, win 7 or Linux there is no software to control the fan after post.
My solution was to open the laptop, cut the red fan wire and solder it to the 5 volt supply of the USB port.

Comment: The temperatures seem to be Ok

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +41.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +47.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

The pwmconfig says there are no capable modules. 

The point is that the fan was always on until the software update.

Comment: If it's running at a decent temp, hasn't crashed or overheated, and it seems ok, then it seems fine. However, long term overheating can be detrimental to your system, so watch out.

Answer (score 1):

To close the question:  when the temperature raises the fan starts to run in a smooth way.  Well done Ubuntu with this OS update!